# Сравнительная степень слов "злющий","сверхмощный" и "ультраправый"?

Tags: словообразование, грамматика

Подскажите, можно ли образовать сравнительную степень от слов "злющий","сверхмощный" и "ультраправый"?

Comment: А как по-вашему, Ирина?  Если посмотреть значения этих слов в толковом словаре...

Comment: Никак нельзя. Ни от одного из этих слов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Из словаря: ЗЛЮЩИЙ, -ая, -ее; злющ, -а, -е. Разг. Очень злой. З. кот, пёс. З. на всех старик.

Слово злющий может иметь  сравнительную степень.

Из Интернета: битва озверевшего пса и **не менее злющего** кота.

Можно, наверное, сказать: эта собака ещё злющее той, но это чисто разговорный (эмоциональный) вариант.

2) УЛЬТРАПРАВЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Связанный с крайне реакционной идеологией.

СВЕРХМОЩНЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Обладающий очень большой мощностью, имеющий большую мощь.

У слов "ультраправый и сверхмощный" **семантика** превосходной степени, поэтому они не употребляются в сравнительной степени.

Comment: Если есть сравнительная степень от "правый" ("правее"), то фонетических ограничений для "ультраправый" нет.

Comment: Да, наверное, окончание при наличии фонетических ограничений должно быть ударным (боевой, рядовой, деловой, передовой).

Comment: Марк, во-первых, фонетические есть.  правый-правЕе, а утраправый дало бы утрапрАвее. А во-вторых, Vera правильно говорит, что тут над на семантику ориентироваться. Я дополню свой ответ.

Comment: @behemothus мой комментарий был написан до изменения Верой ответа и относился к уже удалённой части о том, что от "ультраправый" из-за фонетических ограничений не может образоваться простой сравнительной степени. Вы сами привели вполне возможную парадигму для "ультраправее" (ср. *прекраснее*), которая не применяется только из-за конфликта семантики, а не фонетики.

Comment: Хорошо. Не критично.)))

Answer (score 2):

Теоретически можно. Более злющий, более сверхмощный, более ультраправый.
По крайней мере от "ультраправый" это не выглядит фантастически. 
Ну есть две ультраправые партии, почему одна не может быть более ультраправой, чем другая?

Вот в отношении синтетических форм сравнительной степени (из одного слова) - это вряд ли. По грамматическим причинам "злющее" не воспринимается нормально из-за избыточности (хотя отдельные словари допускают), а два других (сверхмощнее, ультраправее) просто невозможны - конфликт семантики префикса и суффикса.

upd 10.11.2015

По поводу вариантов "более мощный, чем сверхмощный" и более "правый чем ультраправый". С первым еще мог бы согласиться (хотя тоже не лучший вариант по физическому смыслу), а вот второй отвергаю, как неправильный. "Ультраправый" в политике - это качественное отличие от "правого", а не просто крайняя степень правого.

"Более ультрафиолетовый" - это совсем не более фиолетовый, чем ультрафиолетовый. Это скорее наоборот. Это значит, что спектр более видимый, чем невидимый. А более ультрафиолетовый - это именно то, что бОльшая часть спектра лежит в области ультрафиолета. То же самое с политическим спектром.

Более или менее сносно работает только в случае ультракоротких. Более ультракороткие (волны) это отчасти именно более короткие, чем ультракороткие. Хотя тоже надо иметь в виду, что ультракороткие - это качественное. По способности передавать определенный сигнал в определенных условиях.

Так что вариант с "более ультраправый" мне кажется достаточно нормальным.

Answer (score 0):

**Злющий** = очень злой.

Если напрямую образовывать сравнительную степень такого прилагательного (напр. добавлением слов "более" или "не менее"), то возникает смысловая шероховатость: тем, что получается, сравниваются вновь образованные степени не только самого качества (злость), а ещё и степени степеней выражения этого качества (здесь сравниваются ещё и "оченности"). Однако *тот же смысл* в практической речи можно выразить гладко, если не задаваться целью сделать это конкретными частями речи. Здесь в сочетании с исходным прилагательным можно применить сравнительную степень однокоренного ему, тогда выражение степени будет связано только с самим качеством (злость), степени которого хотят сопоставить (пусть от этого и не возникнет желанной сравнительной степени).

```
более злющий, чем Кощей -> злее злющего Кощея
```

(ср. "более очень злой" -> "злее очень злого")

Этот же приём ухода от сопоставления степеней качества позволяет выразить нужный смысл и в двух других случаях, где исходные прилагательные выражают сильную степень качества или диапазон его высоких степеней (**сверхмощный** = более, чем мощный; **ультраправый** ~ крайне правый). Здесь однокоренные прилагательные тоже можно использовать для сопоставления по самому качеству (оно имеет ясную количественную или условную меру):

```
это локатор мощнее сверхмощного английского

эта партия правее ультраправого Национального фронта
```